# My artesian well just ran dry. Do I just wait for it to fill up?

Tags: well-pump

I have been living in my current house for about 8 months now, and this is the first time I have been without water(besides power outages). I noticed that the water was a bit brown so I let the hose run thinking it would flush the muddy water out. I forgot about the hose and ran the well dry. The hose was only running for a few hours. Is there anything I can do? I am guessing I will just have to wait for the well to fill up again. It should be noted that the last couple of days we were putting on multiple loads of laudry, far more than normal.

Comment: Have you audited your water usage? Are you interested in ways to use less water?

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is, depending on the source of the water table, it should fill back up over time. 
But there are many reasons, other than you leaving the hose on for a day, why your well can run dry.
Are there any new building developments in the area? 
Is your region suffering from low rain or snow fall this year?
Or, if there's excessive rain/snowfall, your well could have filled up with excess silt, effectively clogging your well pump.

Answer (score 0):

Its also possible for the well wall to collapse in on itself now that the water isn't there to create pressure and hold the hole walls back. If this has happened you're in big trouble. Start counting your pennies because you're going to need a new well!!

Comment: Hmm - not possible on any well construction I'm familiar with. I rather doubt it.